# Android Studio + Gradle: define resValue without translation, how can I do that?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When defining resources with resValue in build.gradle it is impossible to mark them as translatable="false". In XML this is possible.

Exemple:

In gradle.properties:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

In gradle:

```
resValue "string", "FACEBOOK_APP_ID", FACEBOOK_APP_ID
```

When I want to generate signed APK, there is a translation error on this string because is not translated in other language... but it's normal, I don't want to translate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle doesn't support this **yet**.  You cannot add anything similar to notranslate in your gradle file.

You can add FACEBOOK_APP_ID to exclude lint translation check. **MissingTranslation**

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152198

Comment: Yep, I know I added lint option:    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

Comment: @anthony The issue was fixed, so you can enable back lint translations check.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same error when upload apk in google I resolved it by add **translatable=false**
it's work with me

```
<String Name = "Facebook_app_id"  translatable = "false" >01234567890</String>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add it to values/string.xml with the flag translatable="false"

```
<string name="facebook_app_id" translatable="false">YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID</String>
```

Or you can add the FACEBOOK_APP_ID inside your gradle file, using `resValue` or `buildConfigField`. Something like that:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "string", "facebook_app_id1", "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "string", "facebook_app_id1", "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"
    }
}
```

Usages:

```
// buildConfigField
BuildConfig.FACEBOOK_APP_ID1

// resValue
getString(R.string.FACEBOOK_APP_ID)
```